# Random access iterators and deque

Tags: c++, c++11, deque

I was reading some text today and it stated that since a std::deque does have a random access iterator its item retrieval rate time complexity is O(1). Although I agree with the fact that the time complexity of item retrieval is O(1) but what does having a random access iterator have to do with it ?

Comment: By `item retrieval rate time complexity` they probably mean the complexity of accessing an element by index with `operator[]` (also `at()`). Consider `std::list`; it doesn't have random-access iterators and accessing n-th element is O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RandomAccessIterator` concept requires that the `+` and `-` operations must be implemented in constant time:

From [[iterator.concept.random.access]](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.random.access#1):

> The RandomAccessIterator concept adds support for constant-time advancement with +=, +, -=, and -, as well as the computation of distance in constant time with -. Random access iterators also support array notation via subscripting.

This means that any standard-compliant container that implements a random-access iterator must provide constant-time element retrieval.

Comment: You *could* have a container that lacked `at` and `operator[]` but had random access iterators. What it means is that `reference operator[](size_t i) { return *(begin() + i); }` is a valid implementation